# How to input data within Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have searched for but have not found a solution to this:

Is there a way to create data **within** Jupyter Notebook, particularly tabular data in the form of a pandas DataFrame, via a spreadsheet-like interface as opposed to pd.DataFrame({a:[],b:[]})?

I don't mean read csv or XLwings as solutions, but rather a 'spreadsheet' in the notebook itself so that all information can be edited and stored in one place, and using it feels familiar to a more broad category of people.

Open to creative ideas.

Thanks,

Comment: Since iPython has been forked, do you mean a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Is this something you've tried and failed at? If so, post what you've done and what errors you've seen.

Comment: Yes, I mean Jupyter notebook. I found no such solution when looking around and was hoping someone had a proposal for a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used it myself, but it seems that https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid might fit the bill -- they say that the grid is editable as of v0.3.0.